# How to pass if condition loop output to a variable in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, if-statement, array-map

I need help to solve this

```
let someVar
render(
    {
        this.props.someData.map((items) =>
            items.someotherData.map((item) =>
                (item.data1 > 5 && item.data2 == "more") ? classNames({ "classname1": true })
                    : (item.data1 > 5 && item.data2 == "less") ? classNames({ "classname2": true })
                        : classNames({ "classname3": true })
            ))
    }

    <div className = { someVar } ></div>
   )
```

I need my output of if loop to be pass to the variable
I tried many method. Nothing worked. Please give the solution

Comment: Use the state to set the result and use the same in the JSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
    let someVar

    this.props.someData.forEach(items =>
        items.someotherData.forEach(item =>
            item.data1 > 5 && item.data2 == 'more'
                ? someVar = 'classname1'
                : item.data1 > 5 && item.data2 == 'less'
                    ? someVar = 'classname2'
                    : someVar = 'classname3'
        )
    )

    return <div className={someVar}></div>
}
```

I didn't really get what you were trying to do. Are you calling some function with the class names or something? Here is my best try to solve your problem though.

First we create the variable,
Then we do data processing. You shouldn't use map but instead the forEach if you are not returning anything. You are also overwriting the variable for each item (is this preferred behaviour?).

Then we actually return the React part of the code. Render function always needs to return JSX or null. Inside JSX we can use the someVar in the className. The final value of className needs to be a string. That's why we are putting strings to the someVar.